# Обращение к серверу в Android-приложении

Tags: android, java

Решил создать приложение, главный смысл которого - тесная интеграция с сайтом.
Мне нужно было написать функцию, которая бы занималась обращением к серверу. Написал.

Проверил, но функция возвращает пустоту хотя  все разрешения приложения к интернету есть.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/

public static String loadData(String to) {
    String out = "";
    try
    {
            // загрузка страницы
        URL url = new URL(to);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder allpage = new StringBuilder();
        int n = 0;
        char[] buffer = new char[40000];
        while (n >= 0)
        {
            n = rd.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (n > 0)
            {
                allpage.append(buffer, 0, n);                    
            }
        }
        out = allpage.toString();                 
        return out;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return out; 
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку... или приведите альтернативный код.
К примеру, обращению по урл к веб-странице она должна возвратить `html` код.
Код должен работать на `Android 4.0`.

Comment: Ты бы ошибку вывел... Отловил правильно..  Или подкбажид код...

Comment: А почему не использовать HTTPClient (Он в андроиде вроде в стандартных либах) или HtmlUnit

Comment: А может вся проблема в том, что сайт проверяет user agent? какой сайт пытаемся открыть?

Comment: А зачем InputStreamReader? Там просто InputStream вполне подходит. Проверьте сайт и если все норм, то с чтением косяк.

Comment: Проблему решил через AsyncTask.так и не разобрался в чем причина проблемы....

Должен был открыть обычный сайт вывести html код страницы.
В инете поспрашивал на форумах.все пришло к тому что в Андроид 4
лучше использовать Асинхронный запрос.
лог ошибок у меня нет уже,но андроид мой даже инет не врубал.так что тут примудрости 4 андроида похоже

Comment: Суть в том, что в главном потоке начиная с андроида 3 и выше нельзя запускать код работы с интернетом.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно инфе из комментов проблема была в попытке запустить код работы с сетью для **API<14** на **API>=14**.

Т.к. с **API>=14** работа с сетью в основном потоке запрещена и вызывает `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, то всю логику работы с сетью нужно выносить в отдельный поток используя, например, `AsyncTask`, что и решило проблему автора вопроса.